# How is this Hello World-style swf causing a massive memory leak?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory-leaks, camera, garbage-collection

Make a swf out of this, run it through IE, and watch as your memory keeps growing - and possibly even skyrockets - for reasons that appear to be out of the Flash programmer's control:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class HelloCam extends Sprite
    {
        private var m_tmr:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1);

        public function HelloCam()
        {
            stage ? init() : addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(pEvent:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            (addChild(new Video()) as Video).attachCamera(Camera.getCamera());

            m_tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
            m_tmr.start();
        }

        private function onTimer(pEvent:TimerEvent):void
        {
            removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
            navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://someIP/HelloCam.swf"), "_self");
        }
    }
}
```

This is not isolated to one particular program.  We've been dealing with an issue that started out in much bigger software where, if you have a `Camera` object and a `Video` object, supply a local feed to the user, and keep performing redirects back to the same site, there is a serious memory leak.

(It's worse on some machines than on others, but it's there.  We've also seen instances where it would hit a threshhold, go back a little, and then just skyrocket from there without further hindrance.)

We've tried several things, including wrapping the browser in a .NET program and handling the refreshes through .NET, not through Flash.  We've toggled between different things the site would do in different refreshes.  All that stuff.

This is at the very core of what Flash is and what it's intended for, so is there any way (hopefully aside from using debug swfs and Flash Players) to stop such a memory leak, or is Adobe/Microsoft really this sloppy?

Comment: Does this happen in IE only?

Comment: @Fygo It's possible, but we haven't gone through the full list yet.  We're focussed on IE, because in one of our projects, we've already been spawning a .NET browser object in the code and handling redirects through there.  But in .NET, when you spawn the typical, built-in browser object, it effectively runs as an instance of IE, even in its default state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an IE problem, not a Flash one evidently.  This is true regardless of whether IE is being used normally or through a .NET program with a `WebBrowser` object.

That being said, what we were running into with our code involved the usage of a `WebBrowser` object in VB.NET, and we were handling the majority of our refreshes and redirects through the .NET code, not in the Flash code.  So if you were to take the refreshes out of the Flash code in the question and then relocate them into the .NET code, this is a short example of something that would not have that memory leak:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    <DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint:="SetProcessWorkingSetSize", SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function SetProcessWorkingSetSize(pProcess As IntPtr, dwMinimumWorkingSetSize As Integer, dwMaximumWorkingSetSize As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint:="GetCurrentProcess", SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function GetCurrentProcess() As IntPtr
    End Function

    Private Const URL As String = "http://someIP/HelloCam.swf"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ws.Url = New Uri(URL)
        Timer1.Interval = 5000
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), -1, -1)
        ws.Url = New Uri(URL)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The trick is to:

1. Establish DLL imports for `Kernel32.dll`'s `SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr, Integer, Integer)` and `GetCurrentProcess()` functions.
2. Repeatedly call `SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), -1, -1)`, either around the same time as a redirect or on its own seperate timing.

IE / the WebBrowser object in .NET has an internal memory leak, but this solution gets around the problem by telling the OS to step in and get involved.  By passing `-1` for the second and third arguments to `SetProcessWorkingSetSize`, you cause that function to run in a special mode that examines all the pages in memory for the process, and then trim out the ones that are deemed unnecessary.  Usually this probably isn't the best way to solve memory leaks, but since the API class is internally problematic, it's probably a good idea in this case.

Thanks to Creative Magic's [answer and comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24337422/279112), as well as to studysake's accepted answer to [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-us/88c21427-e765-46e8-833d-6021ef79e0c8/memory-leak-in-ie-webbrowser-control?forum=ieextensiondevelopment).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in this code that would cause memory leaks. It could be or could be not IE problem. Although I find it strange that you "refresh" the app with itself every 5 sec, it's not an elegant solution.

Now to really know where the leak is coming from you'll need to profile your SWF. I recommend to **use Adobe Scout**, it will provide you with detailed profiling like memory, CPU time, garbage collection runs etc.

I think it's the only way you'll really know what causes memory leaks, because you need to remember that Flash runs in a Virtual Machine, so it could be other SWFs that cause a memory leak. Also you're reloading the app and making a new camera every time. It could be just that the garbage collector doesn't run so often and the memory gets allocated until some point when the VM decides to run the GC.

Comment: Unfortunately the company doesn't have Adobe Scout at the moment, but we have tracked the memory leak down to the very usage of a camera and a local feed in IE and the ActiveX plugin.  If we take that out, the problem goes away; but if we add it back in, as in the code above, it just comes right back.  We are seeing this when only one tab is open, with a swf of any scale.  I didn't notice problems though when running this out of Firefox.

Comment: 1) Adobe Scout is for free 2) Perhaps look for some dispose() method on the camera class, maybe Flash VM can send an explicit signal to whatever it's using to dispose of the camera listening. You can do that every time you reload the SWF or upon exit